# How can I add my spinner to the ActionBar?

Tags: android, spinner, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I'm trying to get my spinner working as the Action Bar Drop Down List item, but I cant seem to implement it at all, there aren't many tutorials for this after searching through Google. I think its something to do with the .setListNavigationCallbacks(); line of code, I just have no idea how to get this working from that line onwards.

```
// setup action bar for spinner
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    bar.setListNavigationCallbacks();

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.tools_array_stopwatch, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg2) {
    case 0:     
        break;

    case 1:                 
        Intent countdown = new Intent(this, CountdownActivity.class);
        startActivity(countdown);                       
        break;

    default :                       
        break;
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Step #1: Get rid of your `Spinner`.

Step #2: Get rid of your `OnItemSelectedListener`.

Step #3: Provide your `ArrayAdapter` as the first parameter to `setListNavigationCallbacks()`.

Step #4: Provide an implementation of `ActionBar.OnNavigationListener` as the second parameter to `setListNavigationCallbacks()`.

Step #5: In the `onNavigationItemSelected()` callback method in your `ActionBar.OnNavigationListener`, do whatever it is you want to do based upon the change in the state of the navigation (e.g., execute a `FragmentTransaction`).

Step #6: Redesign your application to not start an activity based on this navigation selection, as you are attempting above. Either start the activity from a toolbar button or options menu item, or use fragments to replace (part of) the UI on the existing activity. List and tabs navigation in the action bar is **not** for launching activities.

Comment: "List and tabs navigation in the action bar is not for launching activities."  Why couldn't an action bar be used to launch activities?

Comment: @JerryBrady: Action items (i.e., toolbar buttons) most certainly make sense to launch other activities.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I would tend to agree, but Google Maps appears to grossly violate this principle on ICS, every entry in the list navigation opens a separate activity. I don't find this particularly odd behavior; instead what puzzles me is how they managed to prevent the spinner briefly receiving the wrong label when an item is tapped.

Comment: You are missing a step.  You also have to set the navigationMode on the ActionBar or it won't work.

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

for example

Comment: For some reason, onNavigationItemSelected gets called once, and not on subsequent interactions with the list.

Comment: On a different note: Is it possible to integrate multiple spinners into the actionbar, say for filtering content within the current activity? So far it seems, only one spinner can be set via the above described method?

Comment: @Zainodis: "So far it seems, only one spinner can be set via the above described method?" -- correct. "Is it possible to integrate multiple spinners into the actionbar" -- not readily.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the clearup. Someone else used a NavigationList and a CustomView, guess that's where I'll be heading as well.

Comment: One question, I have created a custom class extending ArrayAdapter... However, when I write actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, context) it tells me: method setList.... cannot be applied to com.example.myapp.ClassExtendingArrayAdapter... What class should i extend from my custom adapter???

Comment: @BamsBamx: It needs to implement the `SpinnerAdapter` interface.

Comment: Yes, i realized for that before you answered the question.  Thanks for the reply