# Spinner in actionbar android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add spinner to actionbar.
I have three items in actionbar item1,item2,spinner.

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
firstView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_spinner, null);
msg_spinner_wid = (Spinner) firstView.findViewById(R.id.msg_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.msg_spinner_items, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
msg_spinner_wid.setAdapter(adapter);
msg_spinner_wid.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

With above code i can see spinner in action bar but onItemSelected is not getting invoked.I have implemented AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener as well.

if there is any other way to implement spinner in actionbar if anybody knows kindly reply.

Thanks
Vishwajeet

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8662639/985143

Comment: Have a look at this question, this may be helpful.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662173/how-can-i-add-my-spinner-to-the-actionbar