# when greendroid and Actionbarsherlock (ABS) is used in android app

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, greendroid

There are two awesome android UI libs Greendroid and Actionbarsherlock. I want to know when i can use them, which scenario i require these. 
Does both lib provide same functionalists?.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Greendroids implementation of the ActionBar. Use ActionBarSherlock. Greendroid only mimics the ActionBar, whereas ActionBarSherlock is a (almost) 100% backport of the native ActionBar, as found on Honeycomb and above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i need to implement like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833621/custom-spinners-drop-down-menu#. where can i get this feature apart from greendroid?. can you provide some hint

Comment: Yes you are right?. kindly tell me please if you have any idea

Comment: [Please take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662173/how-can-i-add-my-spinner-to-the-actionbar)